# "4K-metal chelated" A chemical term used in Sagan's Cosmos

Tags: terminology, chemical-biology, chemistry-in-fiction

Maybe this question doesn't belong here. It's about a hypothetical xenobiology imagined by a prominent scientist in a seminal work of popular science. So I dunno. Tell me to go away and I'll see if some other SE can help me.

I'll never forget the races Sagan made up in his book *Cosmos*. He gave descriptions of them in the form of excerpts from his imagined *Encyclopedia Galactica*, a compendium of all the races in the galaxy.

There was one term that never made sense to me: "4K-metal chelated". What does the "4K" part mean? Here is the context:

```
Civilization Type: 2.3 R
Society Code: 1H1, "We Who Became One".
Interstellar civilization, no planetary communities, 
  utilizes 1504 supergiants, OV, BV, AV stars and 
  pulsars.
Civilization Age: 6.09 * 10^15 s.
First local initiated contact: 6.09 * 10^15 s ago.
Receipt first galactic nested code: 6.09 * 10^15 s ago.
Source civilization, neutrino channel.
Local Group polylogue.
Biology: C, H, O, Be, Fe, Ge, He. 4K metal-chelated 
  organic semiconductors, types various. Cryogenic 
  superconducting electrovores with neutron crystal 
  dense packing and modular starminers; polytaxic.
```

(By the way, if anyone knows what "Local Group polylogue" is supposed to mean, I care about that too.)

Comment: If you can't find an answer here, maybe the people from https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com will be able to help

Comment: Never actually heard of it, sorry.

Comment: If you didn't get it already there's some of fictional terminology. Fortunately you don't ask about 2.3 R type ;) Still it's quite possible that "4K" was made up.

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like 4 kelvin, i.e. the boiling point of liquid helium under atmospheric pressure, since it mentions cryogenic and superconducting in the next sentence.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto -- I think that's our answer. Helium is in that list of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These guys are "cryogenic superconducting electrovores" who apparently have "no planetary communities" so my guess is that "4K" should probably be taken to mean "4 Kelvin" and "metal-chelated organic semiconductors" as that they are composed of various types of semiconductors whose molecules are organics chelated with a metallic ion. About the "Local Group polylogue" thing, it's probably fictional stuff like a sort of interstellar Commonwealth or something.